# Using Sqoop to migrate views (database tables heavy) from Oracle to Hive

Tags: hive, sqoop, bigdata

I am a beginner in Big Data, we are migrating views from Oracle to Hive, using sqoop, and with Cloudera administration, example of the command we are using:

```
sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts="\-Djava.security.egd=file:/my_url" \ 
  -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=9192 -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx4096m \
  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my_url --username "my_user" \
  --password "my_password" --table my_view_name --compress \
  --compression-codec=snappy --as-parquetfile \
  --create-hive-table --hive-database my_db_name \
  --hive-table our_table_anme --hive-import \
  -m 8 --hive-overwrite \
  --map-column-java column_name=String,column_name=String,column_name=String,column_name=Float --split-by cloumn_name
```

So far it went well, a bit slow with some big boards.

The problem: we have to migrate views with even bigger tables, which will cause problems and we consider hive could not bear the load.

Any suggestions for loading this information?

Note: we think of the option to copy only the table and then try to construct the view, but the view makes complicated modifications on table attributes and heavy calculations, creating this in impala is very complicated in our case.

Comment: Creating view on `HDFS` is kind of overhead. We are also importing entire views as table in Hive. There are few optimization techniques which you can use to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

The template for loading very big tables: Use query instead of table with **where clause to load partition** + use split-column (try to find some integer evenly distributed column). Run sqoop in parallel or sequentially for loading different partitions. Ideally if predicate pushdown will work in Oracle according to your `where` clause. If not, and Oracle side is a bottleneck, then load tables separately using the same technique: where + split, then materialize your view using additional Hive process.

Comment: Thanks , In fact we are already using  --split-by, my apologies that I have omitted it by mistake in the example I have given.

Comment: Yes, I see. It should be exception without split column and with -m